# Finding duplication in 2D wont work when running but when I debugging

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging, multidimensional-array

The purpose of the code is to find duplication of the number 1-9 in each the horizontal rows. Of course when I get it to work I will make it so it will work on vertical rows to.

So this is my code and I think it should be a working code to find duplication in a 2D array in all the horizontal rows.

I have a very strange problem with my Sudoku solving code and it seems to work when I debug but when I run it always says that it finds a duplicate. Is it something I have missed or is the logic in the code totally wrong, it shouldn't be, I'm totally lost after 6 hours.

Here is the code:

```
public bool UniqRowX(Square rutor)
{
    int duplicate = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
    {
        for (int find_duplicate_nummber = 1; find_duplicate_nummber < 10; find_duplicate_nummber++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
                if(rutor.SudokuArray[row, col].nummer==find_duplicate_nummber)
                {
                    duplicate = duplicate + 1;
                }
                if(duplicate>1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate!");
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("No Duplicate");
    return true;
}
```

[Whole Solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13409794/Sudoku%20-%20Nytt.rar)

Comment: Why is there Thread.Sleep(100)? Do you have multithreading involved?

Comment: You should create a proper Data Model where the `Square` class represents a single cell in your sudoku board, as opposed to the entire board, and also contains `Row` and `Column` number properties which you can query against using LINQ instead of that horrible `for` loop from 500 years ago.

Comment: @ThomasW. I removed it, had nothing to do with the code

Comment: @HighCore This is my first "real" objec-oriented project and I have never been working with LINQ so I don't have any qlue how it works and almost all the examples on google I find is for .ASP, not much help there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logic, it looks like you should be setting the 'duplicate' variable to 0 after each pass through the columns.